# Multiple GOPATH's in fish shell

Tags: bash, go

I'm using fish shell. `config.fish` has `GOPATH` environment as:

```
set -x GOPATH $HOME/Documents/Programming/go/3rdparty:$HOME/Documents/Programming/go/own
```

I have two problems.

**1st**: Can't call executables in `3rdparty/bin` directly such as `golocc` or `godep`. I must go in the directory and call it as `./godep` and so on. How can I make `godep` to be called globally.

**2nd**: I can't `cd` to `$GOPATH`. `cd $GOPATH` gives

```
cd: The directory '/Users/xxx/Documents/Programming/go/3rdparty:/Users/xxx/Documents/Programming/go/own' does not exist
```

---

I'm guessing both problems occurs because of my `GOPATH`. What is the problem?

Comment: You need to change your `PATH` - e.g. set -x `PATH $GOPATH/bin:$PATH` - and then `source config.fish` (I assume) to update the current shell.

Comment: @elithrar `PATH` is assigned as `set -x PATH $PATH /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/`. it would conflict I suppose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GOPATH` is only relevant to the Go toolkit, you have to set the `PATH` variable.

Since you have more than 1 folder in your GOPATH you will have to do it like this:

```
set -gx PATH $PATH $HOME/Documents/Programming/go/3rdparty
set -gx PATH $PATH $HOME/Documents/Programming/go/own
```

For the second problem, you simply can't do that, on solution is to have multiple variables for example:

```
set -gx GOPATH1 $HOME/Documents/Programming/go/3rdparty
set -gx GOPATH2 $HOME/Documents/Programming/go/own
set -gx GOPATH $GOPATH1:$GOPATH2
set -gx PATH $PATH $GOPATH1/bin
set -gx PATH $PATH $GOPATH2/bin
```

Then you will be able to cd `$GOPATH1` or `$GOPATH2`

Comment: Could you check my reply comment to elithrar

Comment: @Entei it wouldn't conflict, notice how there's `$PATH` in the set line? you're appending to the variable.

Comment: Over your declarations I added `set -gx PATH $PATH $GOPATH/bin` but it didn't work. So I wrote `set -gx PATH $PATH $GOPATH1/bin` and `set -gx PATH $PATH $GOPATH2/bin` and it started to work. Why didn't the first one work?

Comment: @Entei because you have 2 different paths in `$GOPATH`.